# bokeh requesting resource twice with different http method

Tags: python, http, flask, bokeh

Inside of my Chrome devtools, I see that there is a request for `http://127.0.0.1:5006/bokeh/objinfo/3ca23dfb-07be-4872-80d7-8b34bfcc7a5a/235a1e7e-a77c-461c-85f4-02acab5ee24c` happening twice.

The first time, the http method is `OPTIONS`. This causes the bokeh `crossdomain` decorator to add the correct http header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

The second time, the method is `GET` and I have the following error message in `devtools`:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:5006/bokeh/objinfo/3ca23dfb-07be-4872-80d7-8b34bfcc7a5a/235a1e7e-a77c-461c-85f4-02acab5ee24c. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://45.55.181.194' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

IS the double request an artifact of my imnagination? Is there any other code I could provide to help clear this up?